# jQuery add data attribute to element in code element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Good morning,

I am hanging on a small point and can't get any further.
On my page there is a code field:

```html
<code id="embeddedCodeInline">
<iframe src="https://example.com/inline" frameborder="0" height="500" width="100%" vspace="0" hspace="0" id="inlineIframe" marginheight="5" marginwidth="5" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</code>
```

Above there is an input "color" where the user has the possibility to change the color for a button.
Now I want to place the chosen color as a data attribute in the iFrame:

```js
$('#buttonColorChooser').on('change', function(){
    $('#inlineIframe').data('buttoncolor', $(this).val())
});
```

But the function does not work like this.

***EDIT***
Ok.
This is how I fill the input in the code field. It will be filled by page load.

```js
var embeddedInline = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/css.css"><div class="alert alert-secondary" style="background-color: #f6f6f6!important;"><button id="ce_openOverlay" class="btn btn-church" data-ce_sub="https://example.com/inline" data-ce_eventid="263">Jetzt buchen</button><div id="ce_overlay"></div></div><script src="' + linkJs + '"><\/script>';

$('#embeddedCodeInline').empty().append(_.escape(embeddedInline));
```

Comment: You can try with `$('#inlineIframe').attr('data-buttoncolor', $(this).val())`

Comment: Could you build a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That looks like it should work, given what's been posted so far.

Comment: *"But the function does not work like this."* is not an error description. Be precise.

Comment: No, don't say *"Ok, I missed saying,"*, that's useless. **Edit your question to show what you actually have.**

Comment: ...so if I understand correctly you have a `<code>` element that contains text (which by accident happens to resemble HTML code)? And you want to update this text by setting properties in jQuery? I'm afraid that's not how it works. It's text, after all, not HTML. If you want to modify it, modify it like text: Prepare a template string with a placeholder, and replace that placeholder with an actual value, and update the `<code>`'s `.text()` with with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage in iframe does not support jQuery (it's not linked there). Try opening the website, and using some jQuery code in console.

That's why, you have to use JavaScript for that :

```js
$('#buttonColorChooser').on('change', function() {
  document.querySelector('#inlineIframe').dataset.buttoncolor = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<code id="embeddedCodeInline">
  <iframe height="50" src="https://example.com/inline" id="inlineIframe"></iframe>
</code>

<hr> Type here: <input id="buttonColorChooser">
```

You can see the changes on inspecting :)